# ULN 2803A Relay Driver Circuit

Tags: uln2803

I am building a basic relay driver circuit using ULN2803A. I have attached the basic circuit diagram, i would like to know if i am missing anything. I am Planning to use it with HLKPM01 5V Power supply with this circuit.

After quite a bit of reading on the internet, it seems ULN2803A drops a  large voltage across and thus using it with 5V power supply, the relay will be fed only 3.5V. How to overcome this issue ?, i am quite new to electronics engineering, thus request some assistance from fellow makers.  [image: ULN]

Comment: COM goes to +Vcc not to GND

Comment: Furthermore GND goes to GND.

Comment: Thank you very much Marko.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments you need to ground GND and connect COM to Vin (power for the relays).

If you insist on using the ULN2003, there is no way around the voltage drop, so you can increase the input voltage by a volt or two, or use lower voltage relays (which will draw proportionally more current).

Alternatively, use some other kind of driver such as discrete MOSFETs and diodes (you can use duals for example) or some entirely different kind of driver chip such as TI’s TPICxxx DMOS power shift registers.

Comment: Yes, reading the datasheet is key to success with an electronic component.  Ground to ground,  common to 5v.